# Java - Android - how to add loading screen

Tags: java, android

I have an application at starts up on boot up, I had an issue because it needs an internet connection to run and the wifi wouldn't connect before the app runs, hence I would get a 404 error, but I fixed that issue by doing this:

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

SMSReceiver:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(isOnline(context) == false){

        }else if(isOnline(context) == true) {

            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

    boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

My question is how can I add a loading circle, while its waiting to connect to wifi, in this part:

```
if(isOnline(context) == false){

            }
```

Is this possible? I am very new at java.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you search "Progress dialog in android" in google?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: Yes I did, I found the examples to hard to understand. I tried something over the weekend, I am just trying to find it out

Answer (score 0):

Start the `ProgressDialog` where your process begins

```
 ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(yourActivity.this, "Connecting .....",". Please wait...", true);
```

and when your process is over call `dismiss()` like

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: This gives me an error `ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(SMSReceiver.this);` The constructor ProgressDialog(SMSReceiver.this) is undefined.

Comment: try now,I made things simple and easy,(just in one step)

Comment: and also when you are doing this in a broadcast receiver you need to pass the context **(the one you are passing to onReceive() method)** on the place of yourActivity.this

Comment: Error bacause SMSReceiver is not a activity class so you need to use context variable as a Context.

Comment: New error on show `ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SMSReceiver.this, "Connecting .....",". Please wait...", true);` The method show (Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (SMSReceiver, String, String, boolean)

Comment: Replace smsreceiver.this with **context**

Answer (score 0):

Just Simply use this one.

```
 ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Connecting to Wifi.....",". Please wait...");
```

and when you want to dismiss after process complete just use

```
 progressDialog.dismiss();
```